# Loading and using QGIS plugins in standalone PyQGIS application

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, standalone, quickmapservices

Is there a way to load and use the plugin outside of qgis3, in a standalone python application?

I need to use the quickMapServices plugin to display an interactive basemap and mark points on it.

Answer (score 3):

No. You cannot use a plugin in a standalone PyQGIS script. But you can copy the logic of the plugin by reviewing the whole script of the plugin. This may require a lot of editing and debugging process.

Comment: Thank you very much!